# How can I remotely access the mobile from my computer

Tags: android, c++

I want to access my mobile from my computer  through WiFi or USB cable.   So I just want to know the steps that how can I make it. If anyone can help me please help me 
 To complete my task.
Thank you.

Comment: How is your question related to C++?

Comment: "access" means many things - seems pretty unclear to me

Comment: Actually someone gives me the task that task is when he connect his Mobile to the computer by USB cable or wifi  then he able to start screen video recording  by key board's shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

`adb` tool allows to forward a TCP port from your android device to your computer.

- Attach your device to your computer via USB
- Enable debugging on your device
- `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080`

Once this is done, you may do `socket`,`listen`,`bind`,`accept` in your android c++ program, and connect to it from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the use properly. If you wants to read and write your mobile content through PC(like media,sms, contact) ,you can use software like MobileGo,Mobiledit etc. If u are developer just enable debugger mode in your mobile  setting and contect with PC via USB.